# How can I interrupt Tkinter.Tcl().eval()?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I am trying to create an abort button in a GUI for stopping threads that are blocking on tcl.eval().

```
Class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tcl = Tkinter.Tcl()

    def eval(self, cmd):
        return self.tcl.eval(cmd)

    def stop(self):
        # How can I interrupt a thread which is blocking in
        # self.eval() from here?
        pass
```

Comment: what command are you trying to `eval`?

Comment: I wonder whether anything installs an async event handler, or if the cancellation API has been exposed?

Comment: "stopping threads that are blocking on tcl.eval()"--that would have to be done in the program eval is calling, assuming it is calling a TCL program.  You can use subprocess to run tcl.eval and psutil to kill that parent and any children, or run it as a multiprocessing process, which can then be killed.